# How to compare the lines in two files in the columns ID?

Tags: linux, bash, file, compare

I have two files with dynamic length from 1 to 30 lines, and these data:

```
[File1] 
Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2 
10:50 | Volume | Xxx | 55 | 65 
12:50 | Kate | Uh | 35 | 62 
15:50 | Maria | Zzz | 38 | 67 
15:50 | Alex | Web | 38 | 5 
... 

[File2] 
Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2 
10:50 | Les | Xxx | 31 | 75 
15:50 | Alex | Web | 38 | 5 
...
```

How to compare two files [only ID1 and ID2 columns]: [File1] and [File2] to all first lines of the file {File1] compared with all lines of {File2]. 
If data exists in both files saved to a file [File3] data adding character * 
In addition to the file {File3] have hit other data from [File1].

Result:

```
[File3] 
Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2 
15:50 | Alex | Web | * 38 | 5 
10:50 | Volume | Xxx | 55 | 65 
12:50 | Kate | Uh | 35 | 62 
15:50 | Maria | Zzz | 38 | 67
```

Comment: Is there any expected sort order for the output file?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk  'BEGIN{t="Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2"}
FNR==1{next}
NR==FNR{a[$4 FS $5];next}
{ if ($4 FS $5 in a)
       {$4="*"$4;t=t RS $0}
  else{s=s==""?$0:s RS $0}
}
END{print t RS s}' FS=\| OFS=\| file2 file1

Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2
15:50 | Alex | Web |* 38 | 5
10:50 | Volume | Xxx | 55 | 65
12:50 | Kate | Uh | 35 | 62
15:50 | Maria | Zzz | 38 | 67
```

Explanation

```
BEGIN{t="Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2"}   # set the title
FNR==1{next}                                # ignore the title, FNR is the current record number in the current file.for each file
NR==FNR{a[$4 FS $5];next}                   # record the $4 and $5 into Associative array a
{ if ($4 FS $5 in a)                    
{$4="*"$4;t=t RS $0}                        # if found in file1, mark the $4 with start "*" and attach to var t
else{s=s==""?$0:s RS $0}                    # if not found, attach to var s
{print t RS s}                              # print the result.
```

Comment: DigitalTrauma thank you very much for your help I've added writing to a file at the end:
> File3
And how to do that all the lines from the resulting file File3 been saved variables?

Comment: can you update your request in detail? Give some sample to describe what you need, and put in your original question.